# Azure Release Pipeline is generating error: Unrecognized argument 'Files\IIS\Microsoft'. All arguments must begin with "-"

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Azure DevOps is generating an error when trying to deploy a Release:

> 2023-01-19T17:33:45.9017207Z [command]"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package='D:\a\r1\a\Robbu.Custom.Ed.API\drop\robbu-custom-ed.zip' -dest:auto,ComputerName='https://robbu-custom-ed-beta.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=robbu-custom-ed',UserName='$robbu-custom-ed__beta',Password='***',AuthType='Basic' -setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='robbu-custom-ed' -enableRule:AppOffline -retryAttempts:6 -retryInterval:10000 -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -userAgent:VSTS_4fdfceed-ee54-490c-90de-9dadb1252143_Release__521_859_4

2023-01-19T17:33:46.0034276Z ##[error]Error: Error: Unrecognized argument 'Files\IIS\Microsoft'. All arguments must begin with "-".

We did not change anything in Release settings.

Does anybody know what is this error?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what you are trying to do? Need more details on the task that you have in your release pipeline.

Comment: I'm trying to deploy an Azure App Service

Comment: Which task are you using? Is it an YAML or a classic release pipeline? Also, try to share the input arguments to that task

Comment: The only task is Deploy Azure App Service.

Comment: The arguments are in the question: 
 [command]"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package='D:\a\r1\a\Robbu.Custom.Ed.API\drop\robbu-custom-ed.zip' -dest:auto,ComputerName='https://robbu-custom-ed-beta.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=robbu-custom-ed',UserName='$robbu-custom-ed__beta',Password='***',AuthType='Basic' -setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='robbu-custom-ed' -enableRule:AppOffline -retryAttempts:6 -retryInterval:10000 -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -userAgent:VSTS_4fdfceed-ee54-490c-90de-9dadb1252143_Release__521_859_4

Comment: It seems to be having an issue with "C:\Program Files\IIS", because error message says: "Unrecognized argument 'Files\IIS\Microsoft'."
However, nothing was changed recently in Release Pipeline.
We are deploying this solution to an Azure App Service which runs Windows-2022 image

Comment: Are you using a Linux or a Windows agent? As others have asked, what are the arguments you're providing? The error message is not sufficient, we need to see exactly how you've input the arguments to determine if there's an issue with escape characters or quotation mark usage.

Comment: Windows agent
It seems to be the same problem reported here: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/17634

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem.
Yesterday we create a new release pipeline and worked fine. Today we've got the same error:

```
2023-01-19T21:54:20.4136281Z [command]"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package='C:\azagent\A1\_work\r1\a\temp_web_package_8765182033385763.zip' -dest:contentPath='OpheliaBPM//AssuranceNormative' -enableRule:AppOffline -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule
Failed to deploy web package to IIS website.
Error: Unrecognized argument 'Files\IIS\Microsoft'. All arguments must begin with "-".
Error count: 1.
Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe' failed with exit code 4294967295
```

However, I can see the command before the error is OK, but the problem is maybe Windows is taking the command without quoutes, that's why it assumes that "Files\IIS\Microsoft" should have a "-" before.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/17634